# Router breaks vuetify tabs

Tags: vuetify.js, vue-router, vuetify-tabs

I have some vuetify tabs that work as expected before I add routes.
I want the route to change when the active tab changes.

When I add the :to directive to the the v-tab the routes work correctly (route changes when the tab changes) but the tab items do not display.  The area where the v-tab-item was displayed is now blank.

```
<v-tabs v-model='activeTab'>
  <v-tab
    v-for='cc in cost_centres'
    :key='cc.id'
    :to="{ name: 'Element', params: {id: cc.id}}"
    >
    {{ cc.name }}
  </v-tab>
  <v-tabs-items v-model='activeTab'>
    <v-tab-item 
      v-for='cc in cost_centres' 
      :key='cc.id'>
      <!-- Content -->
    </v-tab-item>
  </v-tabs-items>
</v-tabs>
```

The vuetify docs reference the vue-router docs and I think I am wiring it up right but I just can't get it to work.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

the `:to` was setting the `value` of the `v-tab` and therefore the `v-model` of the `v-tabs` to the **path** instead of the id (or the index of the array).

So I removed the `:to` directive and `watched` the `v-model`.
When the v-model changed I extracted the value (index of the array) and used it to get the cost centre id and then set the route using router.push

On page load (mounted) I use the route param (cost centre id) to find the cost_centre index and set the activeTab v-model.

Answer (score 0):

You might use `<router-view>` instead of the `<v-tabs-items>`:

```js
const Foo = {
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$route.params.id || ''
    }
  },
  template: '<v-card flat>foo {{ id }}</v-card>'
}
const Bar = {
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$route.params.id || ''
    }
  },
  template: '<v-card flat>bar {{ id }}</v-card>'
}

const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    redirect: {
      name: "foo"
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/foo",
    name: "foo",
    component: Foo
  },
  {
    path: "/bar",
    name: "bar",
    component: Bar
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      activeTab: "foo",
      cost_centres: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "bar"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route: function(val) {
      console.log(val)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route)
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-tabs v-model="activeTab">
            <v-tab v-for="cc in cost_centres" :key="cc.id" :to="{ name: cc.name, params: { id: cc.id }}">
              {{ cc.name }}
            </v-tab>
          </v-tabs>
          <router-view></router-view>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

This way the content is not synchronized by the `v-model`, but by the `:to` & the `routes`.

---

### EDIT: NEW SOLUTION

If you just use the query part of the route, then you can control the tabs:

```js
const routes = [{
    path: "/",
    redirect: {
      path: "/0"
    }
  },
  {
    path: "/:idx",
    name: "foo"
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      activeTabRoute: 0,
      activeTab: 0,
      cost_centres: [{
          id: 0,
          name: "foo"
        },
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "bar"
        },
      ]
    }
  },
  watch: {
    $route: function(val) {
      this.activeTab = val.params.idx
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>
          <v-tabs v-model="activeTabRoute">
            <v-tab v-for="(cc, i) in cost_centres" :key="cc.id" :to="{ name: 'foo', params: { idx: i } }">
              {{ cc.name }} {{ cc.id }} {{ activeTab }}
            </v-tab>
          </v-tabs>
          <v-tabs-items v-model="activeTab">
            <v-tab-item v-for="cc in cost_centres" :key="cc.id">
              <v-card flat>
                Name: {{ cc.name }}<br /> ID: {{ cc.id }}<br /> IDx: {{ $route.params.idx }}
              </v-card>
            </v-tab-item>
          </v-tabs-items>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-col>$route: {{ $route }}</v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

I created the snippet above to use the `index` of the `for...in`, because the reflects the order of the tabs, and doesn't mess up the IDs of the items.

This way you can use this component with `vue-router`.

Comment: Thank you. In your answer the routes are separate components that get pulled into the router-view.  Tabs (without routes) seem to work on synchronizing based on the index of the tabs / tab items (which I tested by removing the v-model attributes) of the array that v-for is iterating on.  When I apply the router to the tab items does this totally disable the index synchronizing? Would I then have to stitch everything together in the created and watch hooks?

Comment: @rosscosack A new way came to my mind: don't use different components, only use the param of the route to synchronize the tabs with the tab items. I hope this helps you more.